# Flink Job Execution Failed on run

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to run the data artisans examples available at github. I read the tutorial and added the needed SDKs and downloaded the files for NYCFares and Rides. Whenever i am running the RideCount.java example i get a Job Execution Failed.
Here is the link to the git repo for the RideCount class file.
[Github repo RideCount.java](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/examples/datastream_java/basics/RideCount.java)

here is the error 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the nycTaxiRides.gz file has somehow been corrupted. The line that is shown in your screenshot should have these contents

```
914757,START,2013-01-03 10:00:57,1970-01-01 00:00:00,-73.982796,40.781418,-73.97155,40.761257,1,2013002770,2013017291
```

The code that parses the input is complaining that not all of the fields are present. I suggest you re-download the data file, being careful not to decompress or otherwise alter it. Chrome can do this, or wget, or curl, but some browsers will introduce problems.

Comment: Thanks! The new file is not corrupted and it works just fine.